# Using LinQ to SQL to return Table<tablename>

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a search method that is called "UniversalClientSearch" and is located in a datahandler class. The method searches for data in a table depending on what column and what to search in that column, and then the method has to return a table variable to be used in a datagridview on one of my forms.

I've created a LinQ to SQL statement to get the rows of data that I want, and is saved in a var ReturnSearchQuery, but I don't know how to convert that query to a variable of Table, with the tablename being tbclient.

```
        //Fields
        private DataAccessDataContext db;

        //Constructor
        public Datahandler()
        {
            this.db = new DataAccessDataContext();
        }

        //Method
        public Table<tbClient> UniversalClientSearch(string SearchType, string SearchParameter)
        {
            //This is just here to initialize the variable so it can be changed in the switch
            var ReturnSearchQuery = from Clients in db.tbClients
                                    select Clients;

            //Filters Query based on what column to search
            switch (SearchType)
            {
                case "Client_ID":
                    ReturnSearchQuery = from Clients in db.tbClients
                        where Clients.Client_ID == int.Parse(SearchParameter)
                        select Clients;
                    break;

                case "Client_Name":
                    ReturnSearchQuery = from Clients in db.tbClients
                        where Clients.Client_Name.Contains(SearchParameter)
                        select Clients;
                    break;

                case "Client_Address":
                    ReturnSearchQuery = from Clients in db.tbClients
                        where Clients.Client_Address.Contains(SearchParameter)
                        select Clients;
                    break;

                case "Contact_Number":
                    ReturnSearchQuery = from Clients in db.tbClients
                        where Clients.Contact_Number.Contains(SearchParameter)
                        select Clients;
                    break;

                case "Contact_Email":
                    ReturnSearchQuery = from Clients in db.tbClients
                        where Clients.Contact_Email.Contains(SearchParameter)
                        select Clients;
                    break;

                case "Client_Type":
                    ReturnSearchQuery = from Clients in db.tbClients
                        where Clients.Client_Type == SearchParameter
                        select Clients;
                    break;
            }

            //Make new table to be returned later
            Table<tbClient> ReturnClientsTable = new Table<tbClient>();

            foreach (var item in ReturnSearchQuery)
            {
                //Query has to be converted to Table<tbClient>
            }

            //Table return to be used in datagridview
            return ReturnClientsTable;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReturnSearchQuery` in your code has the type `IQueryable<tbClient>`:

```
// The SQL query isn't run yet
IQueryable<tbClient> ReturnSearchQuery = from Clients in db.tbClients
            where <some condition>
            select Clients;
```

Because of deferred execution, the SQL query isn't executed until you enumerate the `IQueryable`.

```
// Convert the IQueryable to a list. Here, the SQL query is run.
List<tbClient> clients = ReturnSearchQuery.ToList();
```

Finally, you can bind the list of clients to a `DataGridView` by using `.DataSource`:

```
var d = new DataGridView();
d.DataSource = clients;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll incorporate this into my project! 

I got a workaround for it, while I couldn't get the answer, which was to change the return type to dynamic for the **UniversalClientSearch** method, and then just returning the **ReturnSearchQuery**.